# REGEX - NP++ - removing padding 0s from subgroups of a code with one regex

Tags: python, regex, notepad++, pcre

It's my first topic question, thanks in advance for your help and the time you spend to read me
I work under NP++ to try some Regex

## What i want

I would like to get transformed those lines (from) into those formatted lines (to) with **one more attractive and smarter regex** than mine below (see **Unattractive solution**)

**(from) => (to)**

```
H04B0001240000; => H04B 1/24;  
H04B0010300000; => H04B 10/30;  
H04B0011301000; => H04B 11/301;  
H04B0111300000; => H04B 111/30;  
H04B0101303400; => H04B 101/3034;  
H04B0100300010; => H04B 100/30001;  
H04B0110300000; => H04B 110/30;
```

## How to proceed ?

-For a given code, the rules are
`H04B0001240000;`
-Cut into three parts 4, 4 and 6
`H04B 0001/240000;`
-Withdraw all padding 0s at the beginning of the second group (the second group should have at least one digit)
`H04B 1/240000;`
-Withdraw all padding 0s at the end of the third group (the third group should have at least two digits)
`H04B 1/24;`

So the deemed useless 0s are at the beginning of the second group and at the end of third group. The number of padding 0s is varying...

## Unattractive solution

Under NP++, I found a solution that I find unattractive
In 'Search' field :

```
([A-Z])((?:0{3}([1-9]))|(?:0{2}([1-9][0-9]))|(?:0([1-9][0-9]{2})))([0-9]{2})([0-9]*[1-9])?0{1,4}(;)
```

In 'Replace' field :

```
\1 \3\4\5\/\6\7\8
```

**Explanations with `H04B 0001/240000;`**
**==============================**
`([A-Z])` means one capital letter from A to Z, matchs the last letter of the first group (`H04B`)

`((?:0{3}([1-9]))|(?:0{2}([1-9][0-9]))|(?:0([1-9][0-9]{2})))` should matchs 0002 or 0020 or 0201 but not 2011. It concerns detection of the second group (`0001`)

`([0-9]{2})([0-9]*[1-9])?0{1,4}(;)` concerns the third group of 6 digits (`240000`) with with the intention of discard all padding 0s at the end. The third group should have at least two digits `([0-9] {2})`

## Final question

Do you know a more attractive and smarter Regex to reach the aimed result ?

Comment: `\b([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{3})0{0,3}(\d{1,4})(?<=\b[A-Z0-9]{8})(\d{2}(?:[0-9]*[1-9])?)0*;` to replace with `\1 \2/\3;` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDKdok/1)). No idea if it is smart enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

`(?m)^(\S{4})0*(\d\d*?)(?<=^.{8})(\d{2}\d*?)0*;`

https://regex101.com/r/7pTjkB/2

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 ( \S{4} )                     # (1)
 0*
 ( \d  \d*? )                  # (2)
 (?<= ^ .{8} )
 (                             # (3 start)
      \d{2} 
      \d*? 
 )                             # (3 end)
 0*
 ;                             # Or, (?<= ^ .{14} )
```

Or, like this

`(?m)^(\S{4})0*(\d\d*?)(?<=^.{8})(\d{2}\d*?)0*(?<=^.{14})`

https://regex101.com/r/7pTjkB/3

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 ( \S{4} )                     # (1)
 0*
 ( \d  \d*? )                  # (2)
 (?<= ^ .{8} )
 (                             # (3 start)
      \d{2} 
      \d*? 
 )                             # (3 end)
 0*
 (?<= ^ .{14} )
```

Comment: Excellent ! Merci beaucoup !